# Segmentation fault occurs in C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to solve a problem in hacker rank. When I'm running the  following code on my local system, it's not showing any error. But when I submit it, it's showing a `segmentation fault`.

It accepted the first test case, but the remaining test cases do result in a `segmentation fault`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n,q,i,j;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&q);

    int k,l,m,seq,lastAns=0;
    int **arr;
    arr=(int **) malloc(sizeof(int )*n);

    if(!arr) return 0;

    arr[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int )*q*n);

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = *arr + i*q ; 

    if(!*arr) return 0;

    for(i = 0; i < q ; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d%d%d",&k,&l,&m);
        switch (k)
        {
            case 1:  seq= (l^lastAns)%n;
                for(j = 0 ; j < q; j++)
                {
                    if(!arr[seq][j]) 
                    {
                         arr[seq][j]=m; 
                         break; 
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 2:  
                seq= (l^lastAns)%n;
                lastAns = arr[seq][m % n];
                printf("%d\n", lastAns);
                break;
        }
   }   
   free(arr[0]);
   free(arr);       
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arr=(int **) malloc(sizeof(int )*n);` -->> `arr= (int **) malloc(sizeof(int* )*n);` -->> `arr=(int **) malloc(n * sizeof *arr);` ->> `arr= malloc(n * sizeof *arr);`

Comment: Ask yourself what you wish to accomplish with `(int **) malloc(sizeof(int )*n);`?

Comment: i want to allocate memory for n double pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As sjsam pointed out, this statement is wrong:

```
arr=(int **) malloc(sizeof(int )*n);
```

Your program works on systems where `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)` (i.e. 32-bit systems), but will likely fail on 64-bit ones (on which `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(int*) == 8`.

> i want to create a 2d array dynamically of dimension n by q

We understand that, and you *have* created such an array here:

```
arr[0] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int )*q*n);
```

But you are creating something *else* on the problem statement; namely an array of `n` *pointers*, not an array of `n` integers.

Comment: thanks for the help.  i want to create a 2d array dynamically of dimension n by q.